# Firebase Cloud Function - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

A function that reads some documents and passes the result result.
When I build the function I get the following error:
**Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

```
exports.getConfiguration = functions.region("asia-northeast3")
    .https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
        let userConfigData: any;
        let accountData: any;
        let sysConfigData: any;
        if (context.auth == null) {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'The request does not have valid authentication credentials for the operation.');
        }
        const uid = context.auth!.uid;
        const accountRef = firestoreDb.collection('accounts').doc(uid);
        const userConfigRef = firestoreDb.collection('accounts').doc(uid).collection('configuration').doc(uid);
        const sysConfigRef = firestoreDb.collection('configuration').doc('platform');

        try {
            await accountRef.get().then(async (doc) => {
                    const result = doc.data();
                    if ( result ==null) {
                        const user = await admin.auth().getUser(uid);
                        accountData = {
                            'uid': uid,
                            'displayName': user.displayName || null,
                            'email': user.email || null,
                            'emailVerified': user.emailVerified || null,
                            'phoneNumber': user.phoneNumber || null,
                            'photo': user.photoURL || null,
                            'status': 'newUser',
                            'language': 'english',
                            'createdAt': timeStamp.now().toMillis(),
                        };
                        await accountRef.set(accountData);
                        userConfigData = null;
                    } else {
                        userConfigData = await userConfigRef.get().then((doc) => doc.data());
                    }
                }
            );
            sysConfigData = await sysConfigRef.get().then((doc) => doc.data());
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error: ", e);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Unknown error or an error from a different error domain.');
        }
        return {accountData, userConfigData, sysConfigData};
    });
```